# Does this wording (Charge accepted) contain the minimum parts of speech necessary to be considered a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, terminology, sentence-fragments, headline-english, end-punctuation

I know that sentences can be short. "He ran", "I run", etc. are the first examples that come to mind. However, verbal responses to questions like "Yes" are often written with a period after it when I'm quite certain that it's not a full sentence.

One example that my colleagues and I couldn't agree on was "Charge accepted". I know it has a subject (the charge) and a past participle. But, surely it's missing a verb or something that disqualifies it from being a full sentence, thereby making it a little weird to end with a period, right? It even sounds weird without "The", but without "is" or "was" in there, it just doesn't seem like a full sentence.

I know that authors can break any grammatical rules they want at the end of the day though.

Comment: *MODERATOR WARNING*: Got an answer? Post an answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142166/discussion-on-question-by-user15716642-does-this-wording-charge-accepted-conta).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verbless sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143488/verbless-sentence) Or [ fragments in speech vs fragments in novels](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/fragments-in-speech-vs-fragments-in-novels/446060#446060)?

Answer (score 3):

From the *OED*, s.v. Sentence, sense 6 a:

> a. A series of words in connected speech or writing, forming the
> grammatically complete expression of a single thought; in popular use
> often (= period n. 16), such a portion of a composition or utterance
> as extends from one full stop to another. In Grammar, the verbal
> expression of a proposition, question, command, or request, containing
> normally a subject and a predicate (though either of these may be
> omitted by ellipsis).
>
> In grammatical use, though not in popular
> language, a ‘sentence’ may consist of a single word, as in Latin algeo
> ‘I am cold’, where the subject (= I) is expressed by the ending of the
> verb. English grammarians usually recognize three classes: simple
> sentences, complex sentences (which contain one or more subordinate
> clauses), and compound sentences (which have more than one subject or
> predicate).

You can choose which part(s) of this definition you like, and get various answers to your question.

Comment: Well said. Might add that an online message confirming a charge can fit your second definition *if a sentence* is needed at all. It's essentially a rubber stamp saying PAID or CHARGED.