# 'No one she recognized'. A slightly strange sentence

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

Good afternoon!

Can you please tell me the meaning of the phrase:
"**No one she recognized**"

The context is as follows: a woman is watching from afar a stranger who is swimming in her pool. Finally, he comes out and immediately after the author writes: 'No one she recognized'.

Original text:

'*With her elbows propped on the parapet of her terrace, she watched—hard to say for how long—and was taken out of herself, until at the end of a length like any other he did not tumble into a turn, but with his head streaming moonlight came to his feet, and in the same agile movement sprang on to his splayed hands, heaved himself up, and was out.
**No one she recognized.**
A sturdy peasant type, in a bathing-slip that might have been red*'.

*David Malouf. Towards midnight, New York, 2007*

The construction seems a little unusual to me. I would like to hear your opinion on how this sentence should be interpreted.

Comment: It's a sentence fragment. Supply "He was"/"It was". The sentence starting "A sturdy..." is the same. If you search here for sentence fragment there are many similar questions.

Comment: Dear Graffito! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fragments in speech vs Fragments in novels?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/fragments-in-speech-vs-fragments-in-novels) // Note that 'A sturdy peasant type, in a bathing-slip that might have been red.' is also a sentence fragment rather than a sentence.